# Error importing "Esri.ArcGISRuntime" to Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qml, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

After running the code an error came:
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:19:1: **module "Esri.ArcGISRuntime" is not installed**

I am using Qt Creator 4.11.1 Qt 5.14.1
I am using Ubuntu 20.04

I have already added the path to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as stated here: https://developers.arcgis.com/qt/install-and-set-up/

I have restarted the Qt Creator and my system but still not working.
Any suggestions?

The code is:

```
main.qml
```

```html
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import Esri.ArcGISRuntime 100.14 //error here

Rectangle {
    id: rootRectangle
    clip: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    readonly property int initialZoomScale: 8000
    property bool trackingEnabled: false
    property Point lastPosition: null

    // add a mapView component
    MapView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Map {
            Basemap {
                initStyle: Enums.BasemapStyleArcGISDarkGray
            }
        }

        // set initial viewpoint near UCLA, Los Angeles
        ViewpointCenter {
            Point {
                x: -13185535.98
                y: 4037766.28
            }
            targetScale: initialZoomScale
        }

        Button {
            id: button
            text: trackingEnabled ? "Stop tracking" : "Start tracking"
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width: 200
            onClicked: trackingEnabled =! trackingEnabled
        }

        SimulationParameters {
            id: simulationParameters
            velocity: 30
        }

        locationDisplay {
            dataSource: SimulatedLocationDataSource {
                id: simulatedLocationDataSource
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    setLocationsWithPolylineAndParameters(polyline, simulationParameters);
                    simulatedLocationDataSource.start();
                }
            }
            initialZoomScale: initialZoomScale
        }

        // if tracking is enabled then show location history
        locationDisplay.onLocationChanged: {
            if (!trackingEnabled)
                return;

            // clear old route
            locationHistoryLineOverlay.graphics.clear();

            if (lastPosition !== null) {
                polylineBuilder.addPoint(lastPosition);
                locationHistoryOverlay.graphics.append(ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.createObject("Graphic", {geometry: lastPosition}));
            }

            // update last position
            lastPosition = locationDisplay.location.position;

            // update the polyline
            locationHistoryLineOverlay.graphics.append(ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.createObject("Graphic", {geometry: polylineBuilder.geometry}));
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            // Set the focus on MapView to initially enable keyboard navigation
            forceActiveFocus();

            locationDisplay.autoPanMode = Enums.LocationDisplayAutoPanModeRecenter;
        }

        Polyline {
            id: polyline
            json: {"paths":[[[-13185646.046666779,4037971.5966668758],[-13185586.780000051,4037827.6633333955],
                             [-13185514.813333312,4037709.1299999417],[-13185569.846666701,4037522.8633330846],
                             [-13185591.01333339,4037378.9299996048],[-13185629.113333428,4037283.6799995075],
                             [-13185770.93000024,4037425.4966663187],[-13185821.730000293,4037546.146666442],
                             [-13185880.996667018,4037704.8966666036],[-13185948.730000421,4037874.2300001099],
                             [-13185974.130000448,4037946.1966668498],[-13186120.180000596,4037958.896666863],
                             [-13186264.113334076,4037984.296666889],[-13186336.080000836,4038001.2300002342],
                             [-13186314.91333415,4037757.8133333195],[-13186272.580000773,4037560.9633331187],
                             [-13186187.913334005,4037463.59666635],[-13186431.33000092,4037404.3299996229],
                             [-13186676.863334503,4037290.0299995062],[-13187625.130002158,4038589.6633341513],
                             [-13187333.030001862,4038756.8800009824],[-13187091.730001617,4038617.1800008402],
                             [-13186791.163334643,4038805.5633343654],[-13186721.313334571,4038801.3300010278],
                             [-13186833.49666802,4038195.9633337436],[-13186977.677439401,4037699.8176972247],
                             [-13186784.921301765,4037820.4541915278],[-13186749.517113185,4038150.8932846226],
                             [-13186649.860878762,4038288.5762400767],[-13186556.760975549,4038323.9804286221],
                             [-13186472.839936033,4038481.3323777127],[-13186373.183701571,4038489.1999751539],
                             [-13186344.335844241,4038242.6819215398],[-13186126.665647998,4038308.245233661],
                             [-13185814.584282301,4038358.0733508728],[-13185651.987268206,4038116.8003622484],
                             [-13185203.534213299,4038048.6145176427],[-13184576.748949422,4038150.8932845518],
                             [-13184251.55492135,4037833.5668537691],[-13184146.653621957,4037524.1080205571],
                             [-13183949.963685593,4037621.1417224966],[-13183687.71043711,4037781.1162040718],
                             [-13183480.530370807,4037875.5273735262],[-13182307.629999243,4037859.7460188437],
                             [-13181376.039484169,4037820.9297473822],[-13180716.162869323,4038364.3575478429],
                             [-13180182.439136729,4038810.7446696493],[-13178474.523192419,4040237.2426458625],
                             [-13178321.134040033,4039740.6894803117],[-13177958.020228144,4039140.1550991111],
                             [-13177073.512224896,4037459.5898928214],[-13177757.842101147,4037589.9384406791],
                             [-13178386.308314031,4037799.427178307],[-13180095.012208173,4037811.6550856642],
                             [-13180126.165447287,4036845.9046731163],[-13179806.844746364,4036324.0879179495],
                             [-13180928.361354485,4035887.9425703473],[-13181598.155995468,4035428.432293402],
                             [-13182984.47513606,4034447.105261297],[-13182229.264383668,4033222.8051626245],
                             [-13182058.735615831,4033339.8690072047],[-13181939.035180708,4033691.2477038498],
                             [-13182116.65518121,4033861.1450956347],[-13181792.305615077,4034085.1007484416],
                             [-13182027.845180977,4034467.3698799671],[-13181877.254310986,4034644.9898804692],
                             [-13181630.130832028,4034517.5668366305],[-13181386.868657427,4034424.8955320208],
                             [-13181228.555178719,4034652.7124891868],[-13181379.14604871,4034942.3103160923],
                             [-13181267.168222306,4035189.4337950516],[-13181074.103004368,4035015.6750989081],
                             [-13180807.673003616,4034934.5877073747],[-13180618.469090037,4034814.8872722536],
                             [-13180599.162568243,4035374.7764042714],[-13181047.073873857,4035494.476839392],
                             [-13181317.365178969,4035413.3894478586],[-13180765.198655669,4035143.0981427468],
                             [-13180328.871263131,4034892.1133594285],[-13180270.951697765,4035258.9372735149],
                             [-13180325.009958787,4035718.4324922049],[-13180707.279090302,4035695.2646660525],
                             [-13181413.897788007,4035536.9511873648],[-13181618.54691902,4035807.2424924765],
                             [-13181884.976919774,4036065.949884512],[-13182159.129529245,4035861.3007534989],
                             [-13182174.57474668,4035668.2355355616],[-13182417.83692128,4035664.374231203],
                             [-13182784.660835361,4035409.5281435261],[-13182997.032575091,4035255.0759691764],
                             [-13182618.624747934,4034679.7416197238]]],
                "spatialReference":{"latestWkid":3857,"wkid":102100}}
        }

        GraphicsOverlay {
            id: locationHistoryLineOverlay
            SimpleRenderer {
                SimpleLineSymbol {
                    color: "lime"
                    style: Enums.SimpleLineSymbolStyleSolid
                    width: 2
                }
            }
        }

        GraphicsOverlay {
            id: locationHistoryOverlay
            SimpleRenderer {
                SimpleMarkerSymbol {
                    color: "red"
                    style: Enums.SimpleMarkerSymbolStyleCircle
                    size: 3
                }
            }
        }
    }

    PolylineBuilder {
        id: polylineBuilder
        spatialReference: SpatialReference { wkid: 3857 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added it to `QML2_IMPORT_PATH`?

Comment: You can also set the `QML_IMPORT_TRACE` environment variable to see more of the issue. Are you using qmake or cmake?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is this is the correct way to add the path? :
QML2_IMPORT_PATH = /home/nabil/Qt5.14.2/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt100.14.1/sdk/linux/x64/lib

I am using qmake

Comment: I would do `export QML2_IMPORT_PATH=..:$QML2_IMPORT_PATH`. You may also try to include the `pri` file that they suggest here: https://developers.arcgis.com/qt/programming-patterns/best-practices/#qt-quick-qml-api-integration

Comment: I did the export of QML2_IMPORT_PATH. I then added the .pri file using the include command. The code now has no red comments and the error beside the import part is gone. BUT still getting when running/debugging : module "Esri.ArcGISRuntime" is not installed . although the error beside it has gone.

Comment: Have you tried this from their description? `view.engine()->addImportPath("pathToSDK/sdk/macOS/x64/qml");`

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I think the problem now the Qt version since my Qt version is 5.14 and the error is: plugin cannot be loaded for module "Esri.ArcGISRuntime": The plugin '/home/nabil/Qt5.14.2/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt100.14.1/sdk/linux/x64/qml/Esri/ArcGISRuntime/libArcGISRuntimePlugin.so' uses incompatible Qt library. (5.15.0) [release]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will summarise the issues discussed in the comment thread to bring to an end.

1. Use Qt 5.15 these days and preferably always the latest bug fix release. Which is currently 5.15.5 for open-source, and not commercial, customers at the time of writing this. Even better to switch to 6.x when possible.
2. Setting the `QML_IMPORT_TRACE` environment variable can help debugging these issues.
3. When using qmake, [they seem to suggest](https://developers.arcgis.com/qt/programming-patterns/best-practices/#qt-quick-qml-api-integration) including their `pri` file to your qmake `pro` file.
4. Something like a `export QML2_IMPORT_PATH=..:$QML2_IMPORT_PATH` can also help localising these issues as a quick experiment.